# How to put comma between affiliations number of author

Tags: author-number, authorindex

I build a paper with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\title{This is a Test Paper}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\author{
Author A\affmark[1] \affmark[2], Author B\affmark[2], Author C\affmark[2], Author D\affmark[2]\\
\affaddr{\affmark[1]Department of A}\\
\affaddr{\affmark[2]Department of B}\\
\email{\{a, b, c, d\}@tju.edu.cn}
}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

It generates 
[image]

The problem is how to put a comma between `1` and `2` following `Author A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comma can be inserted within `\affmark[1,]`...