# Author alignment and affiliation

Tags: affiliation, author

I am trying to get the author and affiliation section to look like this example:
[image]

My code so far:

```
\documentclass[oneside,twocolumn,9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\newcommand{\titlefont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{authblk}
%
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\small}
%
\pretitle{\huge\bfseries} 
\posttitle{}
%
\title{\titlefont Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci}
\author[1]{Author One}
    \affil[1]{Affil One}
\author[2]{Author Two}
    \affil[2]{Affil Two}
\author[3]{Author Three}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following and costumizing the solution in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314800/how-to-put-comma-between-affiliations-number-of-author). With this solution the Author and Affiliation section can be costumized very well. The new code between the % symbols generates:
[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,twocolumn,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\newcommand{\titlefont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\LARGE}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\normalsize}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
%{
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{, \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother
%}
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\huge\bfseries} 
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushleft}}
%
\title{\titlefont Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci}
\author{
    Author One,\affmark[$\dagger$]
    Author Two,\affmark[$\ddagger$] and
    Author Three\affmark[$\ast$] \\
    \affaddr{\affmark[$\dagger$]Affil One} and \affaddr{\affmark[$\ddagger$]Affil Two}  
}
\date{}
%
\title{\titlefont Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```